# Google reCaptcha has been blocked by Kaspersky Anti- Banner browser plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, recaptcha, kaspersky

I have integrated google reCaptcha to my website and when user trying to login, reCaptcha has blocked by Kaspersky Anti- Banner browser plugin and automatically convert POST request to GET and sends the username and password in clear text as query parameters, refer attached screenshot.

I need to fix this from code level, otherwise my website users get confused and think as security vulnerability, how do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Contact Kaspersky and tell them to fix their software.